# How to change terminal prompt in zsh using YADR

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh

I have been using YADR [Yet Another Dotfile Repository](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) to enable a whole bunch of features in vim.

Given that I split my terminal window, I'd like to reclaim some of the screen estate by shortening the command prompt.

Does anyone know how to edit the zsh files to accomodate this, specifically pertaining to a .yadr setup?

Thanks internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `PROMPT` (and/or `PROMPT2`, `PROMPT3` and `PROMPT4`) in a file with the extension `.zsh` in the directory `~/.zsh.after/`, for example `~/.zsh.after/myprompt.zsh`:

```
PROMPT1='myprompt %# '
PROMPT2='> '
```

Have a look at the sections *EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES* and following in `zshmisc(1)` for some details on zsh prompts.

Also, have a look at the [YADR documentation on themes](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/doc/zsh/themes.md) for more details on how to use premade themes.

Comment: Right under my nose! Thanks for the link to the documentation, I had somehow overlooked this. I have also found that the exact answer I was looking for is in the associated googlegroup pages: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yadr-users/eDhnBry_6qo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just shorten your computer name instead of changing the whole prompt you can issue the command:

```
scutil --set HostName "here"
```